# Django/Wagtail - most efficient way to refine page queryset by multiple parent pages

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a list of category pages obtained as follows:

```
category_ids = request.GET.getlist('category[]')
category_pages = MyCategoryPage.objects.filter(pk__in=category_ids)
```

What I'd like to do is refine a list of pages to include only those that are children of the categories specified above.

I'm aware that you can do this for one object as follows:

```
pages = MySubPage.objects.child_of(category)
```

..but as far as I can tell there is no way to do `child_of(category_pages)` for more than one parent.

In normal Django, where I'd probably have a category `ForeignKey` on `MySubPage`, I'd just do:

```
pages = MySubPage.objects.filter(category__in=filter_categories)
```

..but again I'm not sure that I can do that in Wagtail.

I know I could probably loop through all the categories and append the sub pages to a list:

```
pages = []
for category in category_pages:
    pages.append(MySubPage.objects.child_of(category))
```

...and then join them all, but that doesn't seem very efficient and obviously it would return a list rather than a queryset.

I've searched the docs but can't find any more direct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you can simply look at what is going on in the background when you're calling `child_of` on the queryset. This is what this method and methods of this queryset that it uses looks like (order of their appearance in code not preserved):

```
    def child_of(self, other):
        """
        This filters the QuerySet to only contain pages that are direct children of the specified page.
        """
        return self.filter(self.child_of_q(other))
   
    def child_of_q(self, other):
        return self.descendant_of_q(other) & Q(depth=other.depth + 1)


    def descendant_of_q(self, other, inclusive=False):
        q = Q(path__startswith=other.path) & Q(depth__gte=other.depth)

        if not inclusive:
            q &= ~Q(pk=other.pk)

        return q
```

As you can see, wagtail will just return a queryset with some `Q` objects to filter the list of pages. This filter is based on path to the parent page and depth. To recreate the same filter, but with multiple parents, you can do:

```
import operator

category_ids = request.GET.getlist('category[]')
pages = MySubPage.objects.filter(reduce(
    operator.or_,
    (
        Q(path__startswith=category.path) & Q(depth=category.depth + 1)
        for category in MyCategoryPage.objects.filter(pk__in=category_ids)
    )
))
```

Note that I've optimized the query by removing `Q(depth__gte=category.depth)` from it, because this condition will be met by `Q(depth=category.depth + 1)`. It also doesn't need the `~Q(pk=category.pk)` for the same reason.

Also note that this needs 2 queries in total, which can be optimized to only one query with clever use of `path` and `depth` of categories directly in your `GET` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This looks good - I was looking at the Wagtail code but thought I'd check if I was going along the right lines. Just a few queries: (1) I think your code is missing a parenthesis; (2) my IDE is saying that `__b` is unfilled for the `or_` function, and there is a parameter(s) unfilled for the `reduce` function. Please could you just elaborate on this?

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the above -- works great now!